# Scripted upload to AWS cloudshell environment

Tags: ansible, automation, aws-cli

We maintain dozens of developer accounts on AWS and for maintenance purposes it would be amazing if on all cloudshell environments we would have a set of scripts available. It is possible to upload files to the cloudshell environment manually by using the Actions->Upload File feature in the web console, but that is not feasible to manage dozens of environments. Is there any ansible module or other way to upload files to cloudshell? Probably via S3 bucket, but we're missing the last mile into the cloudshell environment.